# Dataframe to NamedTemporaryFile to then load to S3, but temp file is empty

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I have this dataframe called `df_agg` that I'm trying to load to s3 using airflow's S3Hook.load_file (docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_modules/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.html#S3Hook.load_file)) and I see files being loaded to s3, but the files are empty.

Before creating the temp file I printed out df_agg.head(5) for which I see 5 rows of data, and see below for the printed out `df_agg.info`:

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):

 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------               --------------  ----- 
 0   normalized_page_url  58863 non-null  object
 1   ts                   58863 non-null  object
 2   user_ip_country      58863 non-null  object
 3   imp_id_count         58863 non-null  int64 
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 2.2+ MB
```

this is my code:

```
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', suffix='.csv') as temp:
            df_agg.to_csv(temp.name + '.csv')

            logging.info("temp.tell() size: ", temp.tell())
            logging.info(f'Uploading {temp.name} ... ')

            s3.load_file(filename=temp.name,
                         key=f'S/{company}/pages_transformed/date={ds}/{temp.name}',
                         bucket_name=Variable.get('s3_bucket'),
                         replace=True)
            temp.close()
```

Comment: it looks like you're putting the df into tempfile.csv.csv

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover hi! I'm trying to place the df data into a temp file that is a csv. How would I resolve my issue?

Comment: `df_agg.to_csv(temp.name)` see if this makes a difference

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover hah! this worked, thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!!!